# yii2 add a new item to an object

Tags: php, yii2

After performing

```
$results = TblTrucks::find()->all();
 return $results;
```

I'm getting a new

```
<TblTrucks>
  <id>5022</id>
  <ref_no>2017-1502884906</ref_no>
</TblTrucks>
<TblTrucks>
  <id>5023</id>
  <ref_no>2017-1502884956</ref_no>
</TblTrucks>
```

Now i would like to add a new property so in the model i have

```
public $driver;
```

Now I'm trying to assign a value with

```
 $results = TblTrucks::find()->all();
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    $results[$key]->driver = "test driver"
}
return $results
```

The second return doesn't have the driver attribute or the value where I'm going wrong since i would like display only the new attribute value but not save the value?

I expected to get

```
<TblTrucks>
  <id>5022</id>
  <ref_no>2017-1502884906</ref_no>
 <driver>Test driver</driver>
</TblTrucks>
<TblTrucks>
  <id>5023</id>
  <ref_no>2017-1502884956</ref_no>
  <driver>Test driver</driver>
</TblTrucks>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The second return doesn't have the driver attribute"? What is "the second return"?

Comment: the second return displayed is what i expect to be returned, that is after return $results doesnt contain <driver> as expected .

Comment: user a different variable `$new_results`

Answer (score 0):

[Yii2 Activerecord Guide : Selecting extra fields](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#selecting-extra-fields)

Just change your query as below :

```
$trucks = TblTrucks::find()
      ->select('your_table_name.*,"test driver" as driver') // replace with your table name
      ->all();
```